# use files from stage 1 in stage 2 in azure-pipeline

Tags: azure-pipelines

I have a single pipeline in azure containing two stages: one for building and one for testing:

```
trigger:
- main

stages:
  - stage: 'Checkout'
    jobs:
      - job: 'x86'
        timeoutInMinutes: 60
        pool: <mypool>

        steps:
        - checkout: self
          lfs: true

  - stage: 'CompileAndTest'
    jobs:
      - job: 'UnitTests'
        timeoutInMinutes: 60
        pool: <mypool>
        
        steps:
        - task: MSBuild@1
          inputs:
            solution: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/MyAssembly.csproj'
            platform: 'x86'
            configuration: 'Debug'
```

When executing that pipeline, stage `Checkout` will first checkout the code to `$(Build.SourceSirectory)`, which in my case resolved to `D:\agents\build\_work\3\s`.

Afterwards the stage `CompileAndTest` compiles the code. However MSBuild states

> error MSB1009: project not found, project 'D:\agents\build\_work\4\s\MyAssembly.csproj'

So the variable `Build.SourceDirectory` resolves to different locations between the two stages.

My pool only has a single agent, so I'm sure both jobs run on the same agent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would recommend using the [PublishBuildArtifacts task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/publish-build-artifacts?view=azure-devops)

Would look like:

```
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    pathToPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)' 
    artifactName: 'drop'
```

The reference your folder via the `$(Pipeline.Workspace)` [built in variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#pipeline-variables-devops-services)

Comment: publish my entire source-code as artifact? Won´t that massivly blow up my disk-footprint?

Comment: This can be adjusted to include items for certain paths as opposed to everything.